# Laravel Scheduler with Cron Job

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I'm using larave 5.1 with php5, i try to create my cron job to remove unpaid invoice in time i want, but i testing it to print an userlog to help me know that the job is working.

This is my app/Console/Kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\RemoveUnpaidInvoice::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('removeUnpaidInvoice')->everyMinute();
    // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
}
```

And this is my RemoveUnpaidInvoice class :

```
public function handle()
{
    UserLog::create([
        'user_id' => '3',
        'title' => 'Cron Testing',
        'log' => 'Time : ' . date('H:i:s')
    ]);
}
```

After my files done, i run this command at my terminal to run my cron:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

After i run schedule artisan command, then my terminal show this message :

```
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php5' 'artisan' removeUnpaidInvoice > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &
```

I think it's work, then i check my database to look the userlog is created or not, and it's created, the user log is added new via cron.

But the problem is, i wait for one minute, and no userlog added, wait for 2 minute, 3 minute and more, there's no another userlog added to my database?

How to fix it? am i made a mistake??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Starting sheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling)

> Here is the only Cron entry you need to add to your server:
>
> `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
>
> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. Then, >Laravel evaluates your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

You need start the cron, no run `php artisan schedule:run` in the console.

Comment: I run this command at my console
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
but nothing happen, and run 
* * * * * php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
and nothing happen too

Comment: No, no. `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` should be at `crontab` because it is the cron command. Laravel sheduler work with only cron.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know i must set my crontab.

Comment: How does the scheduler know the last time a given task was run? Does it require a database table to track this?