# Laravel everyTenMinutes not working

Tags: php, laravel, cron

In my Kernel.php file I had :

```
 $schedule->command('tokens:manage')->everyTenMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
```

It did work till 4 days before and now it is not working anymore. I've not made any changes to the Kernel except adding two commands to run.

So I thought it was a memory problem, and modified my TokensManage.php command in order to optimize it. But the problem was still there.

I've modified Kernel.php into :

```
$schedule->command('tokens:manage')->withoutOverlapping();
```

or into :

```
$schedule->command('tokens:manage')->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
```

And it's working, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

withoutOverlapping() creates a file in storage/framework (schedule-*). If the command does not end gracefully, that file will not be deleted, and to the program it will seem that the command is still running.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-task-scheduler-after-fatal-error-when-withoutoverlapping-is-set

Answer (score 0):

You need start the cron.

> Here is the only Cron entry you need to add to your server:
>
> `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
>
> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. Then, >Laravel evaluates your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317967/laravel-scheduler-with-cron-job/37318121) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling).

Comment: It is already done under Forge Laravel for a Digital Ocean server (Ubuntu). Because the thing is other cron commands are running well except this one..