# Scheduling jobs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a command in laravel "update:date" and "php artisan list" successfully lists it. I am able to execute it using "php artisan update:date"

Kernel.php:

```
    protected $commands = [
    'Snuba\Console\Commands\Inspire',
    'Snuba\Console\Commands\UpdateDate'
   ];


protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->hourly();

    $schedule->command('update:date')
        ->everyMinute();

}
```

I configured it to run every minute as given above. Do I need to configure anything else ? I think laravel should automatically register it as cron task on ubuntu server.

Comment: Laravel not register the cron jobs automatically you have to register the Cron Job for the your Laravel App in your system cron tab. Are you registered the cron job of Laravel project in your system? If you do it and it works fine.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::everyMinute()
```

I followed the documentation and thought this is a valid method call. I found that everyMinute() is no more valid in laravel 5+. So, I used cron expression instead.

Comment: or override class https://laravel.com/api/5.x/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html will help you do

Answer (score 0):

> I think laravel should automatically register it as cron task on
>   ubuntu server.

No, you have to start it like:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Starting The Scheduler**

When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server. If you do not know how to add Cron entries to your server, consider using a service such as Laravel Forge which can manage the Cron entries for you

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction)

[Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317967/laravel-scheduler-with-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's command scheduler allows you to fluently and expressively define your command schedule within Laravel itself. For more go through following link [laravel task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SSH
run command crontab -e
insert this line:

- - - - - php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

which will run all your specified crons as there specified times.

If you have cpanel then under crontab add the above line on command

Answer (score 0):

1. If ->everyMinute does not exist, please use ->cron('*/1 * * * * *') to set every minute. Or override class laravel.com/api/5.x/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html
2. If cron job not working, run command **crontab -e** and add this line without single quote
   '* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1'
3. After do this I think it works perfectly.